# Microsoft Azure Luis Publish Key

Tags: azure, azure-language-understanding

I have discovered that the link in Microsoft Azure - LUIS - Quick Start step 2 WOULD NOT direct you to the correct "Language Understanding Portal" link, which should have your region setting specified (e.g. https://au.luis.ai/applications). Instead, it is currently directing to https://www.luis.ai/applications/

And this would lead to a problem that you may not be able to publish your Application with an additional Key.

However, if you create your application on the right link, the publication would work.

[Sucessful publication when the link and region matches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uz5uz.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is documentation for [LUIS website publishing regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-reference-regions) clearly which clearly mentions which website to use for concern region. It clearly states that:

> There are three LUIS websites, based on region. You must author and
>   publish in the same region.

The quick start up link is the sample which demonstrates how to create a LUIS app. The detailed information has been added on different pages which are divided based on the criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the same region whichever you have used while creating resource/Subscription-key than you may be able to publish your API and endpoint.

Kindly read the note given in below URL:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-and-publish-a-luis-model/3-exercise-create-luis-service